# TRIGGER to be executed on update property?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sqlplus

I have a problem with triggers and I can't find why.

These are the tables:

```
create table Properties(  
    idProperties number(10) NOT NULL , 
    Type varchar2(45) NOT NULL,
    ConstructionDate date NOT NULL,
    FloorLocation varchar(20),
    Balkony varchar2(10),
    Price number(10) NOT NULL,
    DateOfInsert date NOT NULL,
    DateOfExiration date NOT NULL,
    Address_FK number(20),
    PropertyType_FK number(20) NOT NULL,
    Service_FK number(20),
    Ownership_FK number(20),
    PropertyService_FK number(20))

create table Services(
    idServices number(10) NOT NULL,
    servicetype varchar2(20))
```

I am trying write a trigger to be executed on update of a `PROPERTY` when the status field is changed from “NEW” to “APPROVED” then update expiration date with today’s date `Sysdate + 90 days`.

I am trying this but it doesn't work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T22
AFTER UPDATE ON Properties
FOR EACH ROW

Begin
  if :new.servicetype = 'APROVED' then
 :new.Servicetype := SYSDATE + 90;

end if;
End;
```

Do I need to call `servicetype` with foreign key from the properties table? Or is this right but I am missing something?

Comment: @IllyricumN. - you should read the formating guide - it makes your post easier to read, and therefore more likely to be answered.

Comment: @DavidKemp, I will do it. Sorry it's my first time I am posting here, I'll keep improving. Thank you

Comment: @IllyricumN. - It would also be helpful to expand on "doesn't work".  Presumably, you get an error message so it would be helpful to post that.

Comment: `servicetype` is a varchar column, you cannot do date arithmetics on it. If you want to store a date in there, declare it as a `date` (or `timestamp`)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change a value in an `AFTER` trigger.  You would need to use a `BEFORE` trigger.

If you're using Oracle 11.2, you should get an "ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type" error if you try to define an `AFTER` trigger that changes a value

```
SQL> create table t (
  2    col1 number,
  3    col2 date
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> create trigger trg_t
  2    after update on t
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.col2 := sysdate + 90;
  6  end;
  7  /
create trigger trg_t
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type
```

On the other hand, if you create the trigger as a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, it should work

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace trigger trg_t
  2    before update on t
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.col2 := sysdate + 90;
  6* end;
SQL> /

Trigger created.
```

Comment: thx for helping me on this. I must update this trigger from properties table to call the foreign key of services which is on properties table, which changes from "NEW" to "APPROVED".

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to select from the service type table to see the actual service description so that you can compare the before and after descriptions.

Also, you'll have to change this to a before update trigger as you are changing the values that are about to be inserted.

```
SQL> select * from properties;

        ID  SERVICEID EXPIRATIO
---------- ---------- ---------
       100          1 26-FEB-12
       200          2 28-NOV-11

SQL> select * from services;

 SERVICEID SERVICETYPE
---------- --------------------
         1 APPROVED
         2 NEW
```

Trigger definition :

```
create or replace trigger trg1
  before update on properties
  for each row
declare
  l_old_servicetype services.servicetype%type;
  l_new_servicetype services.servicetype%type;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('changing from ');

  select servicetype
    into l_old_servicetype
    from services
    where ServiceId = :old.serviceId;

  select servicetype
    into l_new_servicetype
    from services
    where ServiceId = :new.serviceId;

  dbms_output.put_line('old value : ' || l_old_servicetype );
  dbms_output.put_line('nwe value : ' || l_new_servicetype );


   if( l_old_servicetype = 'NEW' and l_new_servicetype='APPROVED') then
      :new.expirationDate := SYSDATE + 90;
   end if; 

end;
/
```

Testing :

```
SQL> select * from properties;

        ID  SERVICEID EXPIRATIO
---------- ---------- ---------
       100          2 28-NOV-11
       200          2 28-NOV-11

SQL> update properties set serviceId = 1 where id = 100;
changing from
old value : NEW
nwe value : APPROVED

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from properties;

        ID  SERVICEID EXPIRATIO
---------- ---------- ---------
       100          1 26-FEB-12
       200          2 28-NOV-11
```

Comment: yes you are right I missed it but even like this it will not work. I am trying to find out how do it from properties table through servicetype foreign key SERVICE_FK

Comment: here it is the reference:                                          alter table Properties add constraint fk_Service FOREIGN KEY (Service_FK) REFERENCES Services (idServices);

Comment: Illyricum N - I have updated my answer with the code.. I think this should help.

Comment: Rajesh Chamarthi - thx a lot, I'll let you know if it works by tomorrow because I don't have sql*plus to try it now. Thank you